Using "though" instead of "but" in "Not only ... but also ..."
Is it possible to use "though" instead of "but" in the "Not only ... but also ..." construction?
For example, instead of

Not only is it interesting, but it can also be pretty helpful.

can I say

Not only is it interesting, it can also be pretty helpful though.

?

Not like that, no. Maybe "Though it is interesting as is, it can also be pretty helpful."

not only...but also... is a set phrase, an idiom.

Have you looked up "though" in a dictionary? It makes no sense to use "though" in the same sentence as "not only", since they both perform the same broad function of indicating there's a further qualification. A native speaker would put emphasis on "also" and dispense with "though", or dispense with "also" and replace "though" with "too".

Though usually introduces something that contradicts what has just been said - a positive following a negative or vice-versa.

It's not very interesting. It can be pretty helpful, though.

